# Div the same height as another div + 100px

Tags: jquery, css

I want head-paint-container the same height as head-container + 100px

I currently have

```
$(".head-paint-container").css({'height':($(".head-container").height()+'px')});
```

How do I add + 100px?

Comment: `$(".head-container").height() + 100` doesn't do what you want?

Comment: No i want the height + 100px

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to add the 100:

`$(".head-paint-container").css({'height':($(".head-container").height() + 100 +'px')});`

And to make it a little more readable:

```
var containHeight = $(".head-container").height() + 100;
$(".head-paint-container").css({'height': containHeight + 'px')});
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery add the 100px to the height.

```
   $(".head-paint-container").css({'height':($(".head-container").height() + 100 +'px')});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.height()` instead of `.css()`

```
$(".head-paint-container").height($(".head-container").height()+100)
```